# Unable to install Kyotocabinet with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, kyotocabinet

I am installing Kyotocabinet for Python3. 
The commands that I ran were:

```
wget http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/pkg/kyotocabinet-1.2.76.tar.gz
tar xzvf kyotocabinet-1.2.76.tar.gz
cd kyotocabinet-1.2.76
./configure && make && make install # takes a couple of minutes
```

This was followed by:
`pip3 install kyotocabinet`

It was successful. However, running a script which includes `from kyotocabinet import *`:

> aviral@sc:~/dev/data-file-handling$ python3 kyoto_learning.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "kyoto_learning.py", line 1,
>   in
>
> from kyotocabinet import * ImportError: libkyotocabinet.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for the answer, you can install kyotocabinet via apt-get for python3 using this command

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-kyotocabinet
```